# How to prevent from reducing or losing values of pixels of a saved Python .mat file after loading in MatlabR2018b?

Tags: python, matlab

I run an algorithm on a three-dimensional image in Python and its output was as a 3D image. Then, I saved the output (type:`ndarray`) using `scipy.io.savemat` to `.mat` format for Matlab.
However, after loading the saved `.mat` file in Matlab the precision of its values is decreased.
Also, this problem occurs for a saved binary image (`ndarray`). That's mean some white pixels are lost after loading in Matlab (a pixel is 1 in Python but it becomes 0 after loading in Matlab).
How to save or load a saved Python `.mat` file without reducing the precision or losing of its pixels in Matlab?

Ex:

Gray Level:

```
Python (ndarray and float64): I(206, 177) = 0.97226
After loading in Mtalab (double): I(206, 177) = 0.8780
```

Binary:

```
Python (ndarray and int32): I(206, 177) = 1
After loading in Mtalab (double): I(206, 177) = 0
```

Comment: Internally MATLAB works with the full 64 bit float, but normally it will only display 5 decimal places; so the precision isn't lost in those case. But here, it sounds less like a case of precision lost, and more like a case of incorrect data. So I'll have to ask for more information on this one. Have you tried simple test cases like saving a single value of `np.float64` to `.mat` file, and checked that it works correctly?

Comment: @mimocha: Yes, I have checked it with a matrix 3x3 (`np.float64`), and it has worked correctly.

Comment: In that case, my only idea is some kind of array index mismatch between python and matlab; especially for higher-dimensional arrays and images. But without more info, I can't say anything definitive.

Comment: Note that Python indexing starts at 0 and MATLAB indexing starts at 1. Make sure you are actually comparing the same pixels!